# Is it illegal to own a rabbit in Queensland unless you're a magician?

Tags: zoology, law, australia

From all that is interesting [How Bunny Rabbits Took Over Australia — And What The Government Is Doing About It](http://all-that-is-interesting.com/bunny-rabbits-australia)

> In Queensland, Australia, it’s illegal to own a pet rabbit unless
>   you’re a magician. Why? Because for the past 150 years, rabbits have
>   caused immense ecological damage to Australia.

Is ownership of rabbits for the purposes of it being a pet illegal in Queensland? Are magicians allowed to own rabbits? And is the exemption limited solely to magicians?

Comment: Comment on English.SE which mentioned this article: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414440/a-single-word-for-non-domesticated-animals-that-live-among-humans#comment990387_414442

Answer (score 244, accepted):

From Queensland's Department of Agriculture and Fisheries brochure [Can I have a pet rabbit?](https://www.daf.qld.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0009/57780/IPA-Keeping-Rabbits-As-Pets-PA15.pdf),

> #### Why are pet rabbits illegal in Queensland?
>
> Rabbits are Australia's most destructive agricultural and environmental introduced animal pest, [...]
>
> #### Can I get a permit for a pet rabbit?
>
> A permit **cannot** be issued for keeping pet rabbits of any
>   variety for any private purpose.
>
> A permit to keep domestic rabbits in Queensland can only
>   be approved if the animal is being kept for an approved
>   purpose:
>
> - certain forms of public entertainment (e.g. magic show
>     and circuses)
> - scientific and research purposes
>
> #### What if it is in a secure enclosure and desexed?
>
> It is often suggested that rabbits should be allowed as pets if they have been desexed and registered. Although desexed and contained rabbits pose minimal risk to the environment and agriculture, there are practical obstacles involved for the mandatory desexing of privately owned animals. [...]